# Calling API during render time in NextJS app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So in my app, am fetching an API response in `getStaticProps()` and populating the layout and content for the main navigation of my page. And passing it to the page component (as prop) for rendering.

But during the time of rendering, I have a couple of keywords. Say for example, `latest_posts`. If such keywords are there, I would like to make an API call and fetch the content depending on the keyword. So I did the other things and it works fine except making the API call at render time using the keyword.

Here's a minimal code (not my actual code, but a stripped down version just to give you an idea):

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { getMenuFromAPI } from '../func/API.js'

export default Home({ menus }){

    // for the meus
    const MenuNav = ( data )=> {
        const a = [];

        //.. here am doing some parsing and extraction of the layout and it's structure from the "data"
        //...

        let output = a.map( ( m, i )=> {
            if( m.type == 'link' ){
                return (
                    <Link href={ a.link }>
                        <a>{ a.name }</a>
                    </Link>
                )
            }
            else if( m.type == 'latest_posts' ){
                //######### do API call here, fetch the data and display
            }
        } )

        return output
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <MenuNav data={ menus } />
        </div>
    )
}



export async function getStaticProps(context) {  
    const menus = await getMenuFromAPI();   // do API call and fetch the whole data

    return { props: { menus } }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I make the API call in the above example? If I use a function, it will show error saying it needs to be async and then the component won't work. Let me know your thoughts or ideas. I have thought about the `useEffect`, but am having hard time trying to figure out a logic on implementing it. Because there would be more than one occurrences of the keywords(eg: `latest_posts`, `movie_cat_five_posts`, etc.)
2. I already have created a `Header` component and am using that in all pages. Since the `getStaticProps()` can be called only from the page level, right now am calling my API method `getMenuFromAPI()` in each page and passing it as props to the page component and then passing it to my custom `Header` component. Is this the proper way or there's a better way?

Comment: Does the code you placed above work?

Comment: @illiachill It's a stripped down version from my actual working code. I mean I typed the necessary portion just to give an example of how am doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure it's 100% correct what I describe here, but I have next logic

1. What you are doing in `getStaticProps` is ok, but you can have API call parameters and get data already with 'latest_posts' as, for example with `?parameters="latest_posts"`.
2. For the `else if` condition, as you are using `nextjs`, you can use [this library](https://swr.vercel.app/). It is something similar to useEffect, check it properly, there are examples, this is really good lib to fetch data client-side
3. How I do the same stuff as you need - you can do all manipulations in getStaticProps.

Code below:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {  
 const menus = await getMenuFromAPI();
 //you can do all manipulations here
 let fetchedData = []
 for (let i=0; i<menus.length; i++){
  if( menus[i].type == 'link' ){
   fetchedData.push(menus[i])    
  }
  else if(menus[i].type == 'latest_posts' ){
    //you do similar as you did in const menus
    //you push data to fetchedData
  }
 }

 return { props: { fetchedData } }
}
```

Then you rework your `MenuNav component`, and return the "styled" and "correct" data with `no client-side manipulations`.

For your question 2: If you correctly did your `Header` component, you can just add it inside your return (as component), nothing will change.

P.S. If you need to apply "filter" after the page is loaded, you need to create a fuction. Behaviour example: you loaded data, you show page to the client, client pressed button "filter" - you need to create a function than reloads data - useSWR will help you. If I misunderstood your question, please, add use-case scenario.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to pull all the data within the `getStaticProps()` rather than going to do the partial one in client side.

Answer (score 0):

`getStaticProps()` will fetch data at **build time**, this means that it will fetch the data when you run `next-build`, you cannot interact with anything in the frontend.

In general you cannot fetch data while a component is rendering like you did in your example.

Instead you can rethink your business logic, and :

Change the logic of `getMenuFromAPI` and if there is a post with type `latest_posts` fetch other data, and the return to the frontend all the data that he needs:

../func/API.js

```
/* 
your code that fetch menu data
...
*/

// filter the data
let filters = ['latest_posts','movie_cat_five_posts']
let needToRefetch = data.filter(el => filters.includes(el.type)
if(needToRefetch.lenght > 0){
      // do something else depending on your needs
      // ex. fetch other data 
}
```

You can do pretty much the same with Hooks, using `useEffect` and `useState` inside `Home` or `MenuNav` :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const MenuNav = ({ data }) => {
  const [myData, setData] = useState(data);
  useEffect(() => {
    let filters = ["latest_posts", "movie_cat_five_posts"];
        let needToRefetch = data.filter((el) => filters.includes(el.type));
        if(needToRefetch.lenght > 0){
            // fetch other data and use setData() to render it
        }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((el, index) => {
        return <a key={index}>{el.name}</a>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I decided to pull all the data within the `getStaticProps()` rather my initial idea of doing certain things on client side.